# c# treeview nodes in winform repeat updates

Tags: treeview

Per the screenshots the price 84.6 repeats itself on the winform, but the underlying treeview has exactly the right nodes (only one)

[image]

[image]

There is not an explicit binding, just play around with updating nodes. What is going on?

The code is just simple `TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();` and add some numbers, etc.

The updates to the code are just not getting into the display, but there's no specific binding.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I had to first of all convert the nodes to a `List<TreeNode>`

`List<TreeNode> tnl = historyTree.TopNode.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToList();`

Then after organising the nodes as required I had to clear the treeview of all nodes and add in the list of nodes

```
historyTree.BeginUpdate();
historyTree.TopNode.Text = q.Name;
historyTree.TopNode.Nodes.Clear();
historyTree.TopNode.Nodes.AddRange(tnl.ToArray());
historyTree.EndUpdate();
```